# Triggering click from Jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

```js
e=document.getElementById('4935-HCI-user-enjoyment');
e.onclick=showCoords;

//If i try this it does alert but screenX and screenY cordinates are undefined
$('#4935-HCI-user-enjoyment').trigger("click");
```

```html
<html><head>
    <title>MINDSEE</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fisheye.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.color.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/html5slider.js"></script> -->

    <script src="js/skynet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/articles.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bubbles.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tickbox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/userstudy.js"></script>
    <script src="js/basket.js"></script>

    <script>
      // LET'S TRY TO HACK SLOW INTERNET RELOAD BUGS
      //$(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).load(function() {
        window.isCrossSite = true;
        skynetInit()
        initBubbles(d3.select('#skynet-bubbles'))
        initTickbox(d3.select('#skynet-tickbox'))
        initUserstudy()


      if("debug" in getURLparams(document.location)) {
        if(localStorage.current_json) {
          loadJson(JSON.parse(localStorage.current_json));
        }
      }
      })
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skynet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/articles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bubbles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tickbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/userstudy.css">
  </head>

  <body style="width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;">
    <form id="skynet-search" style="overflow: hidden; height: 20px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);">
      <h1></h1>

      <p class="search">
        <input type="search" id="skynet-query" name="q" placeholder="scientific search" autofocus="">
        <input type="submit" id="skynet-submit" value="Enter">
        <img class="loader skynet-loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="igniting search..." style="display: none;">
      </p>

      <section class="options">
        <p id="skynet-reranker">
          using <a href="https://wiki.hiit.fi/display/focusarea/DK-Reranker+Interface">reranker</a>
          <input type="radio" id="skynet-reranker-plain" name="reranker" value="plain">
            <label for="skynet-reranker-plain">no-drift</label>
          <input type="radio" id="skynet-reranker-drift" name="reranker" value="drift">
            <label for="skynet-reranker-drift">drift</label>
          <input type="radio" id="skynet-reranker-none" name="reranker" value="none">
            <label for="skynet-reranker-none">drift,no-rerank</label>
          <input type="radio" id="skynet-reranker-partial" name="reranker" value="partial">
            <label for="skynet-reranker-partial">partial drift (testing)</label>
          <input type="radio" id="skynet-reranker-partial" name="reranker" checked="" value="layout">
            <label for="skynet-reranker-partial">new layout (testing)</label>
        </p>
        <p>articles <input type="range" id="skynet-article-count" name="article-count" value="50" min="5" max="100"><span>50</span></p>
        <p class="stash">keywords <input type="range" id="skynet-keyword-count" name="kw-count" value="10" min="1" max="20"><span>10</span></p>
        <p id="dead-keywords" class="stash">
          <label for="keep-dead-keywords">keep dead keywords</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="keep-dead-keywords" name="keep-dead-keywords">
        </p>
        <p id="update-brain" class="brain stash">
          <label for="update-after-drag">update immediately after drag</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="update-after-drag" name="update-after-drag" checked="">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="angular-distortion">use angular distortion</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="angular-distortion" name="angular-distortion">
        </p><p>exploration rate<input type="range" id="skynet-exploration-rate" name="exploration-rate" value="2" min="0" max="5" step="0.1"><span>2</span></p>
        <p>outer ring width<input type="range" id="skynet-outer-width" name="outer-width" value="80" min="5" max="150"><span>80</span></p>
        <p>view sector from angle<input type="range" id="skynet-view-sector-start" name="view-sector-start" value="15" min="0" max="360" step="5"><span>15</span></p>
        <p>to angle<input type="range" id="skynet-view-sector-end" name="view-sector-end" value="345" min="0" max="360" step="5"><span>345</span></p>

      </section>
    </form>

    <svg id="skynet-bubbles" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1150" height="1100">
      <defs>
        <filter id="desaturate">
          <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"></feColorMatrix>
        </filter>
        <filter id="brainboom">
          <!-- COLORIFY #f70 -->
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0   0 0 0
                                                 0 0.5 0 0 0
                                                 0 0   0 0 0
                                                 0 0   0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
        </filter>
      </defs>
    <g transform="translate(100,50)"><g id="background"><path class="center" d="M0,450A450,450 0 1,1 0,-450A450,450 0 1,1 0,450M0,100A100,100 0 1,0 0,-100A100,100 0 1,0 0,100Z" transform="translate(500,500)"></path><image id="megaupload" class="loader keywords-loading" xlink:href="img/ajax-loader-48.gif" alt="updating keywords..." width="32" height="32" x="484" y="484" style="display: none;"></image></g><g id="2457-HCI-user-human-computer-interaction" angle="0.004347376039567533" class="bubble" transform="translate(366.28110686791274,749.4023528092691)"><title>user-human-computer-interaction</title><circle r="70.359375"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-65.359375" y="-65" width="130.71875" height="120"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-36">user</tspan><tspan x="0" y="-12">human</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">computer</tspan><tspan x="0" y="36">interaction</tspan></text></g><g id="2595-HCI-user-usability" angle="0.004347376039567533" class="bubble" transform="translate(395.0571296029419,886.5611694910685)"><title>user-usability</title><circle r="58.3515625"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-53.3515625" y="-41" width="106.703125" height="72"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-12">user</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">usability</tspan></text></g><g id="2553-HCI-user-design" angle="0.004347376039567533" class="bubble" transform="translate(494.6977399531702,773.8269295427324)"><title>user-design</title><circle r="50.359375"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-45.359375" y="-41" width="90.71875" height="72"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-12">user</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">design</tspan></text></g><g id="3369-HCI-user-experience" angle="0.004347376039567533" class="bubble" transform="translate(301.7254229002683,483.7958257430109)"><title>user-experience</title><circle r="73.703125"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-68.703125" y="-41" width="137.40625" height="72"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-12">user</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">experience</tspan></text></g><g id="1503-HCI-user-fun" angle="0.004347376039567533" class="bubble" transform="translate(503.85718782559803,875.5925072235884)"><title>user-fun</title><circle r="41"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-33.34375" y="-41" width="66.6875" height="72"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-12">user</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">fun</tspan></text></g><g id="4935-HCI-user-enjoyment" angle="0.004378240237098398" class="bubble" transform="translate(533.3094874647468,289.3257316478261)"><title>user-enjoyment</title><circle r="70.359375"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-65.359375" y="-41" width="130.71875" height="72"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-12">user</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">enjoyment</tspan></text></g><g id="1103-ip-ip-TCP" angle="0.004378240237098398" class="bubble" transform="translate(591.4440990296514,804.0571281169257)"><title>ip-TCP</title><circle r="41"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-34" y="-41" width="68" height="72"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-12">ip</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">TCP</tspan></text></g><g id="4408-service-ecosystem-service-design" angle="0.004378240237098398" class="bubble" transform="translate(606.7447011482009,906.9333480894975)"><title>service-design</title><circle r="53.0078125"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-48.0078125" y="-41" width="96.015625" height="72"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-12">service</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">design</tspan></text></g><g id="2408-service-ecosystem-trust" angle="0.004409104434629262" class="bubble" transform="translate(682.0334610339107,838.9444695388529)"><title>trust</title><circle r="38.3359375"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-33.3359375" y="-29" width="66.671875" height="48"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="0">trust</tspan></text></g><g id="3196-ip-ip-management" angle="0.004409104434629262" class="bubble" transform="translate(735.0502666577346,718.5593848820793)"><title>ip-management</title><circle r="85.0390625"></circle><rect rx="5" ry="5" style="opacity:0" x="-80.0390625" y="-41" width="160.078125" height="72"></rect><text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:24" alignment-baseline="middle"><tspan x="0" y="-12">ip</tspan><tspan x="0" y="12">management</tspan></text></g></g></svg>


    <!-- <section id="articles"> -->
    <!-- <p class="thicker">You clicked Total Elements:</p> -->
      <!-- <h2>Articles
        <small>
          [<a href="javascript:toggleBasket()"><span class="toggle">show</span> bookmarked (<span class="count">0</span>)</a>]
        </small>
      </h2>

      <ul id="article-basket">
        <li class="debug" id="article-in-basket-unique-article-id">
          <input type="checkbox" id="un-basket-unique-article-id" name="article-un-basket" value="unique-article-id" />
          Title of supreme article
        </li>
        <li class="debug" id="article-in-basket-unique-article-id2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="un-basket-unique-article-id" name="article-un-basket" value="unique-article-id" />
          Other article about the BORGS
        </li>
      </ul>

      <article id="unique-article-id" class="debug new">
        <h3>
          <input type="checkbox" id="to-basket-unique-article-id" name="article-to-basket" value="unique-article-id" />
          <span class="rank">new</span>
          <span class="rank up">↑ 9</span>
          <span class="rank down">↓ 2</span>
          Title of supreme article
        </h3>
        <address class="authors">Authors of your article</address>
        <!--time datetime"2012-01-02">2012-01-02</time-->
        <!-- <p class="keywords">
          <a href="javascript:enterBubble('nuggets', 1)" class="keyword-nuggets">nuggets</a>
          <a href="javascript:enterBubble('poop', 1)" class="keyword-poop">poop</a>
        </p>
        <p class="abstract">Abstract with lots of text making little sense to human.</p> -->
      <!-- </article> -->
     <!-- </section> -->

    <form id="skynet-tickbox">
      <fieldset id="skynet-keywords">
        <legend>Keyword stash</legend>

        

        

        <section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-userhumancomputerinteraction" name="keyword" value="user-human-computer-interaction"><label for="keyword-userhumancomputerinteraction">user-human-computer-interaction</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-userusability" name="keyword" value="user-usability"><label for="keyword-userusability">user-usability</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-userdesign" name="keyword" value="user-design"><label for="keyword-userdesign">user-design</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-userexperience" name="keyword" value="user-experience"><label for="keyword-userexperience">user-experience</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-userfun" name="keyword" value="user-fun"><label for="keyword-userfun">user-fun</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-userenjoyment" name="keyword" value="user-enjoyment"><label for="keyword-userenjoyment">user-enjoyment</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-iptcp" name="keyword" value="ip-TCP"><label for="keyword-iptcp">ip-TCP</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-ipmanagement" name="keyword" value="ip-management"><label for="keyword-ipmanagement">ip-management</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-servicedesign" name="keyword" value="service-design"><label for="keyword-servicedesign">service-design</label></section><section><input type="checkbox" id="keyword-trust" name="keyword" value="trust"><label for="keyword-trust">trust</label></section><input type="submit" id="keywords-submit" value="Update selected to 1">
        <img class="loader keywords-loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="igniting search..." style="display: none;">
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <!--form id="userstudy-alldone">
      <input type="submit" id="alldone-submit" value="ALL DONE" />
    </form-->

  



<script>
function showCoords(event) {
    var cX = event.clientX;
    var sX = event.screenX;
    var cY = event.clientY;
    var sY = event.screenY;
    var coords1 = "client - X: " + cX + ", Y coords: " + cY;
    var coords2 = "screen - X: " + sX + ", Y - coords: " + sY;
    alert(coords2);
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

```js
function showCoords(event) {
    var cX = event.clientX;
    var sX = event.screenX;
    var cY = event.clientY;
    var sY = event.screenY;
    var coords1 = "client - X: " + cX + ", Y coords: " + cY;
    var coords2 = "screen - X: " + sX + ", Y coords: " + sY;
    alert(coords2);
}
```

I have this code when i click on an element it works perfectly but when i try to trigger the click from jquery or javascript mouse event, it returns me undefined for screenX and screenY. How can i make this trigger such that it gives me the accurate corindates.

Comment: or show at least all relevant code. Like how you register the event-listener and how you try to trigger the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout these codes. how about creating a function and calling it on element click

```
function pointerPos(event){
    var cX = event.clientX;
    var sX = event.screenX;
    var cY = event.clientY;
    var sY = event.screenY;
    var coords1 = "client - X: " + cX + ", Y coords: " + cY;
    var coords2 = "screen - X: " + sX + ", Y coords: " + sY;
    alert(coords1);
};
$('a').on('click', function(){
    pointerPos(event);
});
$('button').on('click', function(){
    pointerPos(event);
});
```

Passing the same function on button and `<a>` too.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/h7hypxa0/1/

Comment: When i click on the anchor tag it gives me undefined cordinates in the fiddle code you provided.

Comment: In your code if i do something like $('a').trigger("click"), the same error comes so technically you are not programmatically triggering clicks. This is problem i am having. Please look at the fiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/h7hypxa0/3/

Comment: That will happen because on click you are getting coordinates which are dependent on mouse cursor but if you trigger then it will not get any position of mouse.

Comment: So you mean to say when we try to simulate a click we can never have the cordinates?

Comment: Is there any way to get the mouse cordinates using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('4935-HCI-user-enjoyment').onclick = function() {
        showCoords(event);
    }

    function showCoords(event) {
        var cX = event.clientX;
        var sX = event.screenX;
        var cY = event.clientY;
        var sY = event.screenY;
        var coords1 = "client - X: " + cX + ", Y coords: " + cY;
        var coords2 = "screen - X: " + sX + ", Y coords: " + sY;
        alert(coords2);
    }
}
```

or you can call it from the control itself by adding **onclick** attribute to it like this:

```
 <g id='4935-HCI-user-enjoyment' onclick="showCoords(event)">
```

Comment: These are d3 elements and are not loaded on window.onload, they come after some action being through javascript.